# Ruby on rails - removing routes created by resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following in my routes file

```
resources :users do
    resource :question
end
```

which creates a **/users/:user_id/question** route to **question#show** among other ones. However instead of a URL which has user id in it to show every question the particular user created, I want a URL to show details of one specific question. Something like /question/:id

So to do this I added the line below to my routes file

```
resources :questions, param: :question_id
```

which generated a list of routes

questions_path      GET /questions(.:format)        questions#index
POST                /questions(.:format)            questions#create
new_question_path   GET /questions/new(.:format)    questions#new
edit_question_path  GET /questions/:id/edit(.:format)   questions#edit
question_path       **GET   /questions/:id(.:format)    questions#show**
PATCH                 /questions/:id(.:format)      questions#update
PUT                 /questions/:id(.:format)        questions#update
DELETE              /questions/:id(.:format)

This list produces the **/questions/:id** path but unfortunately with the same **questions#show** connection which collides with the previous one. So I removed the **"resources :questions, param: :question"** and added the following

```
get 'questions/:id', :to => 'questions#show_question'
```

This produces the appropriate route but for some reason doesn't get rid of routes created from **"resources :questions, param: :question"** even after restarting the server. So every time i visit /question/:id it's going to question#show instead of question#show_question

How do i get rid of the effect of **"resources :questions, param: :question"** even after having removed it from the routes.rb file?

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the route `get 'questions/:id', :to => 'questions#show_question'` 
and use shallow routes instead

```
 resources :users do
  resources :questions, shallow: true
 end
```

And then your url_helper should be

```
<td><%= link_to 'Show', question_path(question) %></td>
```

This allows URLs for resources that otherwise would be deeply nested such as a comment on a blog post like /users/a-long-permalink/comments/1234 to be shortened to just /comments/1234.

More info on shallow routes here http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html